# How can there be block mining rewards in Rootstock?

Tags: mining-reward, sidechains, rootstock

I'm trying to understand Rootstock a little better, and am still not sure about the mining rewards they mention in their [white paper](https://uploads.strikinglycdn.com/files/90847694-70f0-4668-ba7f-dd0c6b0b00a1/RootstockWhitePaperv9-Overview.pdf):

> RSK uses the DECOR+ block reward sharing scheme to reduce competition and allow miners late switch to the
>   RSK best block. If miners switch their hardware each time a RSK block is found, they
>   compete for a full RSK block reward. If they late switch, and keep mining past block tips,
>   they create uncles and and earn a share of the block reward.

But how does this mesh with the pegged 1:1 exchange rate of BTC to RSK? The people behind Rootstock [specifically state](https://webonanza.com/2015/10/14/qa-with-rootstock-its-a-hybrid-merged-minedfederated-sidechain/) that new coins aren't generated, only bought with BTC. Is the block reward the transaction rewards?

Thanks!